# Migrate Active Reports v7 for silverlight to latest v13 with webdesigner

Tags: angular, silverlight, activereports, grapecity

I have an application that uses `Active Reports` with `Silverlight` support (version 7). It has support for both viewing and designing reports. I want to port the whole application to Angular using latest version of `Active Reports 13` which supports web designer for `Angular`. I also want to use as much of existing code and logic to avoid re-writing the code.

Is there a way of doing same to port the code easily to web designer ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation and sample below:

https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#HowToCreateaSimpleWebDesignerSample.html

https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#ViewingreportsusingJSViewer.html

https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR13/webframe.html#JSViewer_Angular(Core).html

The process for embedding the JSViewer in an Angular application would be the same as the Web Designer, however, you would have to use the Web Designer resources files instead of the JSViewer files.  If you would like help with this, please reach out to our support team by creating a ticket here: https://supportone.componentone.com/newcase

Best Regards,

GrapeCity Support Team

Comment: Using JS file libraries are very troublesome in Angular SPAs. The reference to JS libraries using <script> tags is not allowed in most cases (completely not allowed in my case). It would be more helpful if Grapecity provides npm packages for designer and viewer. This will help in a cleaner design and implementation.

Comment: Could you provide CDN links for all the js that are required for designer and viewer. This might help in solving the problem a little.